# Changing the order of summation and integration

Tags: integration, summation, permutations, combinations, exponential-sum

Can I interchange the summation and integration of the following quantity ?

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{k-1}{i} (-1)^i \int_{T}^\infty e^{-(\frac{1}{\theta_1}-\frac{u}{k})(n-k+1+i)t}dt=\int_{T}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{k-1}{i} (-1)^i  e^{-(\frac{1}{\theta_1}-\frac{u}{k})(n-k+1+i)t}dt $$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if both limit exists. That is just a finite sum and the result follows from the fact that $\lim (a_1 + a_2) = \lim a_1 + \lim a_2 $ if both exists

Comment: Yes, since the upper limit of summation is finite.

Comment: @Ant which limits are you referring in my case ? Probably I am missing a point.

Comment: @Dr.MV could you please explain it why ? Probably I am posing a stupid question !

Comment: Can you show that $\int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx=\int f(x)+g(x)dx$?  What about $\int f(x)+g(x)+h(x)dx$?  Can you do it, in general, for any finite sum?